# Adjust for multiple comparisons in regression with one outcome variable and several independent variables?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate

How do I adjust for multiple comparisons using FDR with linear mixed effects

first regression:

```
   IV: amount of water, amount of fertilizer, amount of sunlight
   DV: crop growth
   interaction effect: location of crop (factor)
```

second regression:

```
   IV: amount of water, amount of air pollution, amount of sunlight
   DV: crop growth
   interaction effect: location of crop (factor)
```

third regression:

```
   IV: amount of carbon dioxide, amount of fertilizer, amount of sunlight
   DV: crop growth
   interaction effect: location of crop (factor)
```

How can I adjust for multiple comparisons in this case? Do I adjust for each regression test so only the 3 tests? Or do I adjust for each independent variable (5 different independent variables) and one dependent variable the crop growth so that's a total of 10 variables I'm adjusting for. Also should I adjust for the interaction effect? Yes they are all part of my research question.

Comment: Also, I can't put them in the same model for my research question